# Looping javaBean attributes

Tags: java, loops, attributes, iteration, javabeans

I have a java bean

```
public class Bean {

private Object field1;
private Object field2;

public Object getField1() {
    return field1;
}

public void setField1(Object field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}

public Object getField2() {
    return field2;
}

public void setField2(Object field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}
}
```

I want to set the fields so I'm doing this hardcoded

```
Bean c1 = new Bean();

c1.setField1(hmap.get(headers[1]));
c1.setField2(hmap.get(headers[2]));
```

I would like to do this with a cycle because I have 17 fields.

```
for (count = 1; count < headers.length; count++) {
c1.setField1,2,3...("Parameter_" + count, messages.getString("field." + headers[count]));}
```

How can I implement this? Using JDK 16

Comment: Since your field count is not fixed, I would suggest use single field which will be a `Map<String,Object>` , where key will be your header name, instead of having separate field for each header

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  Always specify in your question as that will influence the available answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), as follows:

```
    Bean c1 = new Bean();

    c1.setField1("Object 1");
    c1.setField2("Object 2");

    for (int count = 1; count < headers.length; count++) 
    {
        //concatenate to get method name
        String methodName = "getField" + count;

        // using reflection, get collection of all methods in Bean class
        Method[] methods = Bean.class.getMethods();

        for(Method method : methods)
        {
            if (method.getName().equals(methodName))
            {
                // if it's the method you want, invoke it using 
                // the required params
                method.invoke("Parameter_" + count, messages.getString("field." + headers[count]));
            }
        }
    }
```